# Why my afterResponse method is not being called in my AWS lambda function?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to make contact form on my static website hosted on Amazon S3 & CloudFront. I decided to write simple program in Java for AWS Lambda and invoke it from my static website through AWS API Gateway.

Here is my LambdaHandler class:

```
public class LambdaHandler extends RequestHandler2 {

    FormData formData = new FormData();

    public LambdaResponse handleRequest(FormData formData, Context context) {
        this.formData = formData;
        System.out.println(String.format("Hello %s.", formData.getName()));
        Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
        headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        headers.put("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        return new LambdaResponse(200, headers, "{}");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterResponse(Request<?> request, Response<?> response) {
        System.out.println("afterResponse");
        try {
            sendMail(formData.getName(), formData.getEmail(), formData.getCompany(), formData.getPhone(), formData.getSubject(), formData.getMessage());
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

**The problem is that the `afterResponse` method is not being called**. I need to send an e-mail after returning the response because sending e-mails (through Amazon SES BTW) can take up to 13-18 seconds (especially when lambda function is called after a while of being unused) and I don't want users to wait that long.

In my AWS Lambda configuration I have `com.example.emailservice.LambdaHandler::handleRequest` as a handler.

Comment: I suggest using the @override annotation to make sure the method is really being overridden.

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't work.

Comment: Are you sure it's not failing? Add an `afterError`.

Comment: @teppic Thanks but `afterError` is not being invoked as well. I added `System.out.println("afterError");` and I can't see that output in CloudWatch while `Hello {name}` (where `{name}` is a parameter from the request) is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a second Lambda function whose only responsibility is calling the `sendMail` function. Then you should have your current LambdaHandler invoke the second Lambda function as an "event" (so you don't wait for it to finish) just before returning your LambdaResponse instance.

Comment: Is it really necessary? What would be `afterResponse` for?